# Matlab vs Python: Reshape

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, numpy, scipy

So I found [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html):

> When converting MATLAB code it might be necessary to first reshape a
>   matrix to a linear sequence, perform some indexing operations and then
>   reshape back. As reshape (usually) produces views onto the same
>   storage, it should be possible to do this fairly efficiently.
>
> Note that the scan order used by reshape in Numpy defaults to the 'C'
>   order, whereas MATLAB uses the Fortran order. If you are simply
>   converting to a linear sequence and back this doesn't matter. But if
>   you are converting reshapes from MATLAB code which relies on the scan
>   order, then this MATLAB code:
>
> ```
> z = reshape(x,3,4);
> ```
>
> should become
>
> ```
> z = x.reshape(3,4,order='F').copy()
> ```
>
> in Numpy.

I have a multidimensional 16*2 array called `mafs`, when I do in MATLAB:

```
mafs2 = reshape(mafs,[4,4,2])
```

I get something different than when in python I do:

```
mafs2 = reshape(mafs,(4,4,2))
```

or even

```
mafs2 = mafs.reshape((4,4,2),order='F').copy()
```

Any help on this? Thank you all.

Comment: Could you post some sample input and the desired (MATLAB) output for people who do not have MATLAB available to test with?

Comment: I would point out that reshape(mafs,(4,4,2)) will be a syntax error, while reshape(mafs,[4,4,2]) is not.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Example:

#### MATLAB:

```
>> mafs = [(1:16)' (17:32)']
mafs =
     1    17
     2    18
     3    19
     4    20
     5    21
     6    22
     7    23
     8    24
     9    25
    10    26
    11    27
    12    28
    13    29
    14    30
    15    31
    16    32

>> reshape(mafs,[4 4 2])
ans(:,:,1) =
     1     5     9    13
     2     6    10    14
     3     7    11    15
     4     8    12    16
ans(:,:,2) =
    17    21    25    29
    18    22    26    30
    19    23    27    31
    20    24    28    32
```

#### Python:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mafs = np.c_[np.arange(1,17), np.arange(17,33)]
>>> mafs.shape
(16, 2)
>>> mafs[:,0]
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
>>> mafs[:,1]
array([17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32])

>>> r = np.reshape(mafs, (4,4,2), order="F")
>>> r.shape
(4, 4, 2)
>>> r[:,:,0]
array([[ 1,  5,  9, 13],
       [ 2,  6, 10, 14],
       [ 3,  7, 11, 15],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16]])
>>> r[:,:,1]
array([[17, 21, 25, 29],
       [18, 22, 26, 30],
       [19, 23, 27, 31],
       [20, 24, 28, 32]])
```

Comment: so matlab's reshape function always uses the fortran order. to have the equivalent reshaping output in python, we need `order='F'` argument. Right???

Comment: MATLAB arrays are stored in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) (be it 2D matrices or arrays with more than two dimensions). The [RESHAPE](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function returns a copy whose elements preserve their columnwise ordering, only the "shape" of the new array is changed. The corresponding Numpy function allows you to specify the order you want (C or Fortran order, with C being the default). If you want to do the same in MATLAB, you'd need PERMUTE in addition to RESHAPE.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue myself, as I am also trying to make the transition from MATLAB to Python.  I was finally able to convert a numpy matrix, given in depth, row, col, format to a single sheet of column vectors (per image).

In MATLAB I would have done something like:

```
output = reshape(imStack,[row*col,depth])
```

In Python this seems to translate to:

```
import numpy as np
output=np.transpose(imStack)
output=output.reshape((row*col, depth), order='F')
```