# Translate reshape from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm using numpy and I don't know how translate this MATLAB code to python:

```
C = reshape(A(B.',:).', 6, []).';
```

I think that the only right thing that I did is:

```
temp=A[B.transpose(),:]
```

but I don't know how translate all of the rows.

example of matrix:

```
A =

 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 1     5
 1     6
 2     3
 2     4
 2     5
 2     6

B =

 1     2     3
 1     2     4
 1     2     5
 1     2     6
 1     2     7
 1     2     8
 1     2     9

C =

 1     2     1     3     1     4
 1     2     1     3     1     5
 1     2     1     3     1     6
 1     2     1     3     2     3
 1     2     1     3     2     4
 1     2     1     3     2     5
 1     2     1     3     2     6
```

Comment: Can you include an example of input and desired output?

Comment: This might be a more accessible question if you described what the Matlab code *actually did*. Have you read any of the various guides to `numpy` for Matlab users?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892358/matlab-vs-python-reshape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an indexing plus reshaping operation; one thing to keep in mind is that numpy is zero-indexed, while matlab is one-indexed. That means you need to index `A` with `B - 1`, and then reshape your result as desired. For example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2],
              [1, 3],
              [1, 4],
              [1, 5],
              [1, 6],
              [2, 3],
              [2, 4],
              [2, 5],
              [2, 6]])

B = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [1, 2, 4],
              [1, 2, 5],
              [1, 2, 6],
              [1, 2, 7],
              [1, 2, 8],
              [1, 2, 9]])

C = A[B - 1].reshape(B.shape[0], -1)
```

The result is:

```
>>> C
array([[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4],
       [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 5],
       [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 6],
       [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4],
       [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 5],
       [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 6]])
```

One potentially confusing piece: the `-1` in the `reshape` method is a marker that indicates numpy should calculate the appropriate dimension to preserve the size of the array.

Comment: it's working I didn't know the use of `A[B-1]` instead of `A[B-1,:]` thanks

Comment: `A[B-1]` is the same as `A[B-1,:]`.  numpy is just filling in the rest of the indexes for you.  The 2nd form is clearer - to me.