# different result loading binary files matlab and python

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to read a binary file from a readout board that will be converted to an image. In Matlab, all the bytes are correctly read and the image is completelly populated. But in python (ver2.7 using anaconda) there is a line of zeros every 127 columns. 
The Matlab code is:

```
fid = fopen(filename);
Rawdata = fread(fid,'uint8');
Data1d = Rawdata(2:2:end).* 256+ Rawdata(1:2:end)  ;
% converts Data1 to a 2D vector, adding a row of zeros to make the reshape
% possible to 3D
Data2d = [reshape(Data1d,4127,1792); zeros(1,1792)];
% reshapes again, but adding a new dimension
Data3d = reshape(Data2d(:),129,32,1792);
% selects the first 128 values in the first dimension 
Data3d = Data3d(1:128,:,:);
Data2d = reshape(Data3d(:),4096,1792);
Data2d = Data2d';
CMVimage = Data2d;   
fclose(fid); %VGM 2017-01-14 the file should be closed.
```

In python I tried np.fromfile() and directly reading from python using f.read()
with the same result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
"""
reads the input .dat file and converts it to an image
Problem: line of zeros every 127 columns in columns: 127,257,368...
curiosly, the columns are in the position of the new byte. 
In matlab it works very well. 
"""


def readDatFile(filename):
""" reads the binary file in python not in numpy
the data is byte type and it is converted to integer. 

    """
    import binascii
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    data = f.read()
    #dataByte = bytearray(data)

    f.close()
    data_out = []
    for num in data:
        aux = int(binascii.hexlify(num), 16)
        data_out.append(aux) 
        #print aux

    myarray = np.asarray(data_out) 
    return myarray 




def rawConversionNew(filename):
    # reads data from a binary file with tupe uint
#    f = open(filename, 'rb')
#    Rawdata = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.uint8)
#    f.close()

    Rawdata = readDatFile(filename)

    ## gets the image
    Data1d = 256*Rawdata[1::2] + Rawdata[0::2]               
    Data2d = Data1d.reshape(1792,4127)
    Data2d = Data2d.T 
    Data2d = np.vstack([Data2d,np.zeros((1,1792),dtype=np.uint16)] )
    Data3d = Data2d.reshape(129,32,1792)
    Data3d = Data3d[0:128,:,:]
    #plt.figure()
    #plt.plot(np.arange(Data3d.shape[0]),Data3d[:,1,1])
    #print (Data3d[:,0,0])
    CMVimage = Data3d.reshape(4096,1792).T

  return CMVimage
```

Comment: Are you sure your indexing is correct? I've had trouble converting matlab to python in the past and it was all down to the indexing of arrays...

Comment: thanks @DavidG. there were in fact two errors, not labeling the file as binary ("rb") and the reshape, which is done in a different way in Matlab and numpy.I tried to upvote and accept your reply, but I did not manage.

Comment: Probably best to write the answer yourself and then mark it as accepted as I didn't really do much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were in fact two errors, not labeling the file as binary ("rb") and the reshape, which is done in a different way in Matlab and numpy.
If the reshape is done using reshape(dim1,dim2,order='F') the results are the same. Check: [Matlab vs Python: Reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892358/matlab-vs-python-reshape)